# Snippet of CSS that will display a paragraph in blue in older browsers, red in newer browsers, green in IE6 and black in IE7

Tags: css

Is there a way to Write a snippet of CSS that will display a paragraph in blue in older browsers, red in newer browsers, green in IE6 and black in IE7.

From My side I make this snipped but not sure it will work, Is any one know another snippet to make it work.

```
#content p{color:blue}
html>body #content p {color:red}
* html #content p{color:green}
html>body #content p {*color:black;}
```

Comment: What interview is this for?

Answer (score 0):

This is a trip down horrible memory lane:

```
* p { color/**/:blue; } /*IE5*/

* html p { color: green; } /*IE6*/

*:first-child+html p { color: black; } /*IE7*/

p { color: red; } /*The rest*/
```

Here's a reference I've fortunately not had to refer to for years: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

If you have to support IE 5 in any way you have my deepest sympathies.

Comment: old means <IE6 new means- >IE7

Comment: read this "Mister Epic" http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Answer (score 0):

This may help-

```
html body #content p {
       color: red; /* all browsers including Mac IE */
       *color: black; /* IE 7 and below */
       _color/**/: blue; /* IE 5.0 */
       _color:/**/ blue; /* IE 5.5 only */
       _color/**/:/**/ green; /* IE 6 only */
    }
```